# What is wrong with this method of loading external csv data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to d3. I am trying to load external csv data. I have this code

```
var data = d3.csvParseRows("https://github.com/josh-flori/inner_state_viz/blob/master/inner_state_data.csv", function(d, i) {
   return {
      xx: +d[0],
      yy: +d[1],
      radius: +d[2],
      t: d[3],

   };
});
```

But when print data to the console it shows as

```
[[object Object] {
  radius: NaN,
  t: undefined,
  xx: NaN,
  yy: NaN
}]
```

Maybe I'm just really tired but I've been looking around online for an hour and am completely unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me why you're using `d3.csvParseRows`. According to the documentation, `d3.csvParseRows`...

> Parses the specified string, which must be in the delimiter-separated values format with the appropriate delimiter, returning an array of arrays representing the parsed rows. Unlike dsv.parse, this method treats the header line as a standard row, and should be used whenever DSV content **does not contain a header**. (emphasis mine).

Your CSV, on the other hand, clearly contains a header:

```
xx,yy,radius,t
151,440,8,asdgasdg
270,178,2,asdgg
198,401,7,gg
394,317,7,gg
466,429,10,ggdsdd
```

On top of that, what you have here is a proper CSV, not a string.

That being said, use `d3.csv` instead. Pay attention to the fact that, unlike `d3.csvParseRows`, `d3.csv` returns a promise. Finally, given the CSV header, you don't need that row conversion function in your example.

Here is the demo:

```js
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josh-flori/inner_state_viz/master/inner_state_data.csv").then(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```